# Discord Bot Code: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'Latency'

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a function that reports its WebSocket latency. My code is shown below:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "+", intents=intents)

@client.command(name="ping", help="This is a ping command")
async def ping(ctx):
     await ctx.send(f"**Pong** Latency: {round(client.Latency * 1000)}ms")
```

When I attempt to run my code, I get an AttributeError saying that the variable `Latency` is not a property of my discord bot.

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'Latency'

I've tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you want to call is `latency` with a lowercase l, not an uppercase L.

```
await ctx.send(f"Latency: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")
```

---

Both [Pycord](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.latency) and [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.latency) mention the casing of the variable and its usage in their documentation.